# How do I convert day of year data to a date without an error?

Tags: r

I have data in one column that is a day of year stored as an integer (1-365). When I try to use `as.Date` to convert it to a date, I get an error.

From this code:
`df$date <- as.Date(df$day, origin = "2021-01-01")`

I get this error:

```
`Error in df$day : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`
```

Comment: What does df$day look like? That above should work. Although you should update your origin to "2020-12-31". Otherwise it will start on "2021-01-02"

Comment: can you please add what your data looks like so we can better help you

Comment: it is not possible to transform an integer only to date format. Date format should have day month year.

Comment: Run `str(df)`, for it to work `day` needs to be `numeric`, if it is `character` or `factor` your code will fail. If that is the case try `as.Date(as.numeric(df$day), origin = "2021-01-01")`

Comment: Also as an aside - you really shouldn't create a variable named `df`. `df()` is an actual function. So in your call, R thinks that you are trying to subset the function `df` which is why you get that specific error.